# How to login to multi-tenant application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I have a multi-tenant application that works fine when I login from the same tenant but fails to work when logging in as a user from a different tenant.  As an example, I get the same behavior when running this multi-tenant Web API sample:

active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store

Logging in from the same tenant works fine.  When logging in as a user from a different tenant than the one hosting the Web API I get the following error:

The error:

> AADSTS70001: App with identified [GUID] was not found in the directory
>   [some_tenant]

Just a couple of points:

- I modified the web api's AD application registration: the Multi-tenanted switch is set to Yes; the knownClientApplications property in the manifest includes the application id of the client application.
- The client is failing on a call to AcquireTokenAsync.  The resource in that call is the App ID URI from the web api's AD app registration.
- The authority used in the client is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried signing in to the application using an administrator account of the other tenant?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried an administrator account.  Basically, the consent prompt that I would expect to appear after entering my credentials doesn't... so I just get an error that indicates the application isn't in the user's tenant (without the consent this is expected).   Has there been some change since this sample was published where we have to do something different to get the consent prompt to come up?

Comment: Can you please describe your setup? How many applications in play here? (2? Client and Resource?) Are both registered in the same tenant, but different than the one you are trying to sign into? What is the specific login url you are trying to use to sign in?

Comment: There's one client and one service resource registered in the same tenant. The authority is  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common and the resource passed to AcquireTokenAsync is the App ID URI from the service's AD app registration.  Logging in as a user from the same tenant works fine.  Logging in as a user from a different AD tenant produces the error above-- and it's notable that I never get a consent prompt after entering my credentials.  I can reproduce the same behavior in the active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store sample app

Comment: Here's a full link to the sample: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel indicated I edited the manifest for the AD client application and set **availableToOtherTenants** to true.

[Updated client manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neVrw.png)

Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure all the settings are correct. Here is the figure for the settings for your reference:

[image]

After that, the code sample works well and the two apps are register to the test tenant:
[image]

Comment: Yes.  All of those settings are as you indicate.  In addition to the other settings I mentioned in my post is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: No. There is no additional settings required. It is helpful if you can upload the figures about the detailed steps you have confined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your apps in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) have `"availableToOtherTenants": true` for both the client and service app.